# Disable an input element when a dependent element has changed value

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
<input type="password" placeholder="oldPass" id="passwordcyu" class="input-xlarge" name="passwordcyu">

<input type="password" placeholder="newPass" disabled=true class="input-xlarge" name="passwordmoi" id="passwordmoi">

<input type="password" placeholder="confirmPass" disabled=true class="input-xlarge" name="cfpw" id="cfpw" style="display:inline">
```

Hi everyone, I'm a new guy in javascript/jquery, I have three inputs text like above. I don't know how to disable inputs #newPass and #confirmPass when #oldPass has changed value. Please help me or give me some advises.

P/s: This is the first time I raise a question on stackoverflow. Sorry if I make someone feels uncomfortable about my question.

Comment: so bind onchange handler on element, select the other element, disable it.

Comment: @epascarello sorry I do not know you mean so well. Hm...I want to use jquery to catch every id of input.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that since your elements are *already* disabled in your HTML, you'll likely want to *enable* them. (This also fits the implied use case.)

The simplest jQuery-based answer for you would be to bind your element to a `change()` handler and disable the inputs as you see fit:

```js
$("#passwordcyu").change(function() {
  $("#passwordmoi, #cfpw").removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="password" placeholder="oldPass" id="passwordcyu" class="input-xlarge" name="passwordcyu">

<input type="password" placeholder="newPass" disabled=true class="input-xlarge" name="passwordmoi" id="passwordmoi">

<input type="password" placeholder="confirmPass" disabled=true class="input-xlarge" name="cfpw" id="cfpw" style="display:inline">
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Pure javascript live example:

```js
function changeInputs() {
  document.getElementById("passwordcyu").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("passwordmoi").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("cfpw").disabled = false;
}
```

```html
<input type="password" placeholder="oldPass" id="passwordcyu" onchange="changeInputs()">

<input type="password" placeholder="newPass" disabled="true" id="passwordmoi">

<input type="password" placeholder="confirmPass" disabled="true" id="cfpw">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `prop` and `disabled` the other input whenever old password is clicked . i.e :

```js
//when oldpass is click 
$("#passwordcyu").on("click",function(){
$("#cfpw , #passwordmoi").prop("disabled", true);
});
//when new password is click enbaled it 
$('#passwordmoi ').closest("div").click(function () {
   $(this).find("#cfpw,#passwordmoi").attr("disabled", false);
   
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="password" placeholder="oldPass" id="passwordcyu" class="input-xlarge" name="passwordcyu"><br/><br/>
<div>
<input type="password" placeholder="newPass"  class="input-xlarge" name="passwordmoi" id="passwordmoi"> <br/><br/>

<input type="password" placeholder="confirmPass" class="input-xlarge" name="cfpw" id="cfpw" style="display:inline">
</div>
```